# not able to sort list in tcl

Tags: sorting, tcl, ns2

I have below code in NS2 which calculates distance between two nodes and put it in a list "nbr". I want to sort out that list in ascending order as per value "d" and again store it in a list for further use for that I used `lsort` command but it is giving me same list that is unsorted.
please help

code:.

```
proc distance { n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
    set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
    set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
    set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
    set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]
    set d [expr int(sqrt(pow(($x2-$x1),2)+pow(($y2-$y1),2)))]
    if {$d<300} {
        if {$nd2!=$nd1 && $nd2 == 11} {
            set nbr "{$nd1 $nd2 $x1 $y1 $d}"
            set m [lsort -increasing -index 4 $nbr]
            puts $m
        }
    }
}

for {set i 1} {$i < $val(nn)} {incr i} {
    for {set j 1} {$j < $val(nn)} {incr j} {
        $ns at 5.5 "distance $node_($i) $node_($j) $i $j"
    }
}
```

output:

```
{1 11 305 455 273}
{4 11 308 386 208}
{5 11 378 426 274}
{7 11 403 377 249}
{8 11 244 405 215}
{9 11 256 343 154}
{10 11 342 328 172}
{12 11 319 192 81}
{13 11 395 196 157}
{14 11 469 191 231}
{15 11 443 140 211}
{16 11 363 115 145}
{17 11 290 135 75}
{18 11 234 121 69}
{19 11 263 60 132}
{20 11 347 60 169}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're calculating each of the distances separately, but aren't actually collecting them all into a list that can be sorted.

Let's fix this by first rewriting `distance` to just do the distance calculations themselves:

```
proc distance {n1 n2 nd1 nd2} {
    set x1 [expr int([$n1 set X_])]
    set y1 [expr int([$n1 set Y_])]
    set x2 [expr int([$n2 set X_])]
    set y2 [expr int([$n2 set Y_])]

    set d [expr int(sqrt(pow(($x2-$x1),2)+pow(($y2-$y1),2)))]
    # Why not: set d [expr hypot($x2-$x1,$y2-$y1)]

    # I'm keeping *everything* we know at this point
    return [list $nd1 $nd2 $n1 $n2 $d $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2]
}
```

Then, we need another procedure that will process the whole collection (at the time the simulator calls it) and do the sorting. It will call `distance` to get the individual record, since we've factored that information out.

```
proc processDistances {count threshold {filter ""}} {
    global node_
    set distances {}
    for {set i 1} {$i < $count} {incr i} {
        for {set j 1} {$j < $count} {incr j} {
            # Skip self comparisons
            if {$i == $j} continue

            # Apply target filter
            if {$filter ne "" && $j != $filter} continue

            # Get the distance information
            set thisDistance [distance $node_($i) $node_($j) $i $j]

            # Check that the nodes are close enough
            if {[lindex $thisDistance 4] < $threshold} {
                lappend distances $thisDistance
            }
        }
    }

    # Sort the pairs, by distances
    set distances [lsort -real -increasing -index 4 $distances]

    # Print the sorted list
    foreach tuple $distances {
        puts "{$tuple}"
    }
}
```

Then we arrange for that whole procedure to be called at the right time:

```
# We recommend building callbacks using [list], not double quotes
$ns at 5.5 [list processDistances $val(nn) 300 11]
```

Comment: thank you so much for help.I have one more question.I want to access this sorted list outside procedure.like i have to `lassign [lindex $sortedfile 0 2] a`..which file i should call in place of "$sortedfile"

Comment: I have tried to use distance file i.e sorted list outside procedure using global. I have created one more variable inside procedure  after `set distances` , made it global and assign distances file to that variable.but when i use that file outside procedure error occurs  `can't read "file" : no such variable`